# Is there way to mange several big sqlite file using R or SQLlite?

Tags: r, sqlite

I would like to make database by managing and merging several big sqlite file.
There are 100 sqlite3 file and totally the size is 500GB.

For small database (<2GB), I used R for importing and merging the several sqlite file such like:
(It might be basic code combining R and sqlite)

```
  temp_path = "D:/Wi-Fi/data/13. Campus sensing/"
  temp_filename_sqlite3 <- list.files(path= temp_path, pattern = "sqlite3$",
                                      recursive = TRUE)

  load_sql <- function(list){
    lists <- paste0(temp_path, sprintf("%s", list))
    db <- tbl(dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = lists), "packets") %>%
      collect()        
  }
```

When I run the code for big dataset(100 files totally 500GB), I got an error (Error: cannot allocate vector of size 22.4 Gb).

Should I should use sqlite program (i.e., DB browser for SQLlite)? However there is no code for importing and loading several sqlite files for merging them.

I'm a beginner to use the SQL so I would like to get hint for making the database.

Comment: I don't think R is the solution for this problem.

Comment: I agree with you. There are some mentions; We should deal with the db for stable one using SQL not R.

Comment: Unless you have like a 1TB ram, I don't see how you can process this in R

Comment: What do you mean by merging?

Comment: There is just 64 RAM on my computer... Merging means, 1) reading a sqlite (among 100 files); 2) do something (filtering) or not; 3) saving the sqlite to db; 4) repeating other sqlite files (99 files). Each rows in different 100 files will be in one database (one table).

Comment: I'd use sqlite bash, load one db, filter, dump as flat text file, do this for all dbs, then *cat* all files into one, then use sqlite to create table from that final one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > `However there is no code for importing and loading several sqlite files for merging them.`

The sqlite3 program provides ATTACH for loading multiple sqlite databases, though the number of databases that can be attached at any one time is small:

> The ATTACH statement is an SQLite extension that allows two or more databases to be associated to the same database connection and to operate as if they were a single database. The number of simultaneously attached databases is limited to SQLITE_MAX_ATTACHED which is set to 10 by default. The maximum number of attached databases cannot be increased above 125.

<sup>https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html</sup>

DB Browser for SQLlite does support ATTACH, but given your memory requirements and constraints, you'd probably be better off focusing on the sqlite3 executable.